# extract text from pdf by type python

Tags: python, pdf, text

[image]

Hi everyone,
I have this sample of pdf file, I have more than 30 files and each one consist in avarg of 10 pages.
as you can see, each paragraph conists of three types of text fonts and color,
I **want to convert the pdf file to cvs file or xls file**, where each type in separate coulmn.ALso, **I want to exclude the highlited text in yellow**.
somthing similar to this :
[image]

What are `python libries` should i use? any orianttion or suggestion will be helpful
Thanx

Comment: Your question is not appropriate for StackOverflow: "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers."

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries out there. I have worked with https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/ before. It will probably work well for your use case.

```
pdf2txt.py my_text.pdf
```

Comment: thank u 4 ur answer.. what about divide the text by the font type ? how to separate them by type?

Answer (score 0):

To operate with the pdf files, u can use PyPdf2

Comment: how to separate text by font type, and ignore the highlited text ??